# Как сделать повторный мердж ветки, после его отмены

Tags: git, git-merge

Всем привет. Вопрос по git. Есть 2 ветки. Dev и master. Было слияние дев в мастер, а после была отмена слияния.

Так как слияние уже было, все коммиты, которые были сделаны в dev, теперь в истории в ветке мастре. Однако после отмены слияния, сами изменения в коде были отменены. После этого продолжилась работа в ветке dev.

Вопрос: Если снова слить dev в master, применятся ли все изменения или будут только те коммиты, которые после мерджа?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под отменой слияния? Вы откатили mster ветку?

Comment: *сами изменения в коде были отменены* — отмените их точно так же.

Comment: Я сделал revert. В результате проиндексировались коммиты. После этого продолжилась разработка в ветке dev. Теперь снова ее нужно слить, но так чтоб применились все коммиты. Даже те которые были проиндексированы и отменены ранее с помощью revert

Answer (score 1):

Если сделать мердж 1 ветки в 2, все коммиты в первой ветке проиндексируются. Даже если сделать revert, в коде все веренться как до слияния, но коммиты остануться проиндексированы. Это значит, что если продолжить изменения в 1 ветки и снова слить, будут применены только коммиты после слияния.

Если нужно заново применить ВСЕ коммиты из первой ветки, нужно сделать revert на том коммите, где было отменено слияние.

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: Если снова слить dev в master, применятся ли все изменения или будут только те коммиты, которые после мерджа?

Применятся только те изменения, которые были после последнего смерженного коммита

Comment: А есть способ применить все изменения?